# iOS simulator build issue - "library not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcodebuild, i386

I need to create simulator build for Facebook review.
I have 2 targets in my project - the app sources & static library.

I have tried the steps described at Facebook tutorial.

I used next command:`xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1`

But build failed with error 
"library not found for -lOOyalaAllSources" 
and one more 
"The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386"

OOyalaAllSources - the name of static library I used.

How can I fix this issues?

Comment: It looks like it can't find the library. It might also mean that the library hasn't been compiled for i386 arch. You can find out by running `lipo -info OOyalaAllSources.a `